# How to select image in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to download the six images in this link in the zoomed version.

https://www.venus.com/viewproduct.aspx?BRANCH=7~63~&ProductDisplayID=71352

But if you take a look at the HTML, you will find out that just the first one is in the selected mode. I can simply click on the rest of them and change the class to the selected and then download all of them. How can I do this automatically using selenium?

Comment: What do you mean by just the first one ? The image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page you can get the original image source from the preview images.

```
previewImages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='previews']//img")
for origImages in previewImages:
    previewurl=origImages.get_attribute("src")
    local_image_filename = wget.download(previewurl.replace("?preset=productalt",""))
    print(local_image_filename)
```

Above code gets the original image url from preview images and downloads them using wget. You need to import wget for this to work.